# Why are my predicted values constant?

Tags: r, geospatial, predict, kriging, geor

## mydata

```
mydata_x <- rep(seq(200,600,by=200),times=1,each=4)
mydata_y <- rep(seq(600,1200,by=200),times=4,each=1)
mydata_z <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,529,0,0,0,0)
mydata <- data.frame(x=mydata_x,y=mydata_y,z=mydata_z)
```

I've taken samples from a virtual field and now want to predict neighboring values.  It's been done by the two methods described below... both predicting a constant value for each point.  I don't understand why.

Keep in mind that I'm a new R user and love it.  I've been trying to follow an example I found online to perform my task.  Using the example dataset, I have no problem achieving their outcome.  However, I'm unable to apply it to my own data.  See the example here:  [http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/statistics_c173_c273/c173c273_lec11_w11.pdf](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Enchristo/statistics_c173_c273/c173c273_lec11_w11.pdf)

```
require(geoR)

#create x,y coordinates for locations to predict

kx <- rep(seq(250,700,by=100),times=1,each=length(seq(650,1250,by=100)))
ky <- rep(seq(650,1250,by=100),times=length(seq(250,700,by=100)),each=1)  
k_df <- data.frame(x=kx,y=ky) #coordinates as data.frame
k_matrix <- as.matrix(cbind(kx,ky)) #coordinates as.matrix

#convert sample data (top of post) as.geodata

b <- as.geodata(mydata)

#predict values

prediction <- ksline(b,cov.model = "gaussian",cov.pars = c(10,3.33),locations=k_df)
prediction$predict
```

All 35 outcomes return 44.0833 #I just don't get it!!!

I don't understand how I am returning a single value across the field when there are so many zeros.  I would expect to see a single region of decreasing values.

## Thoughts?

Comment: I only listed a single method here, contrary to my initial statement.  The second method used was the function krige.conv.  The predicted values using this method also come out constant.

Comment: I've found that asking the code to predict a much higher number (~500) of values within the grid produces better results.

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for including sample data and code, which is more than most people do... Unfortunately, your code does not run as is: the second line should have `times=3`. This may not seem like a big deal, but if you expect people to help you, it's really not reasonable to force them to struggle through simple errors like that.

Comment: The 'times=' code was meant to run for the number consistent with the 'length' of that sequence.  For the example, I should have removed that variability to make it easier to read.  I'll keep that in mind for next time.  You helped me greatly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
prediction <- ksline(b,cov.pars = c(10,200),locations=k_df)
cbind(k_matrix,prediction$predict)[12:20,]
#        kx   ky            
#  [1,] 350 1050  93.6977130
#  [2,] 350 1150 292.2674563
#  [3,] 350 1250 329.6293038
#  [4,] 450  650   0.5934677
#  [5,] 450  750  -0.1541056
#  [6,] 450  850  -2.9329553
#  [7,] 450  950   1.8124209
#  [8,] 450 1050  93.6977130
#  [9,] 450 1150 292.2674563
```

The kriging algorithm calculates an estimate for a prediction point based on values at "nearby" data points (discounted for distance from the prediction point). The "range" element (second element) of `cov.pars=...` controls how far to look for "nearby points". You had it set to 3.33, whereas the nearest point was ~ 50 units away. So basically the algorithm wasn't using any nearby points, and the estimate for all points is then simply the mean of all the data values.

Comment: Deep down I knew that I had misunderstood one of these variables.  Now both the ksline and krige.conv codes are working beautifully, and providing similar results.  Thank you greatly for your help.